# Python way to join subsets of an element into a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code...it works, but is there a better way to do it?

So if the participant list is `[ { 'Id': 5, 'name':'bob'}, {'Id': 4, 'name': 'sally'} ]`, result should be `'5, 4'`.

```
participant_list = obj['participants']

id_num = []

for participant in participant_list:
    id_num.append(str(participant['Id']))

result = ",".join(id_num)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with `str.join`:

```
>>> participant_list = [ { 'Id': 5, 'name':'bob'}, {'Id': 4, 'name': 'sally'} ]
>>> ", ".join([str(p["Id"]) for p in participant_list])
'5, 4'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map()`, This works -

```
>>> participant = [ { 'Id': 5, 'name':'bob'}, {'Id': 4, 'name': 'sally'} ]
>>> ",".join(map(lambda x: str(x['Id']), participant))
'5,4'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
>>> ','.join([str(i['Id']) for i in participant_list])
'5,4'
```